# Install Fedora 25 no UEFI

Tags: fedora, boot, live-usb

I've seen this question: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/75022/install-fedora-22-x64-in-legacy-mode-without-uefi/ but this doesn't help me.

I can only boot from USB stick when UEFI is enabled in BIOS (otherwise it doesn't appear in the list of bootable devices).  I don't want to use UEFI for my permanent installation, but I want to dual-boot (I have MS Windows installed by the shop which sold me this laptop in a non-UEFI mode, and I don't want to destroy this installation).

PS. I can boot from live USB.  Is there any way around anaconda and it wanting to unconditionally create EFI boot?

---

The exact same problem exists in Fedora Workstation 24, 23 and 22.  At this time it doesn't make sense to try earlier versions because the updater was completely broken in 21, so even if they could install, updating wouldn't be possible.

Comment: You might have to add the USB stick to the boot device list in the BIOS when UEFI is disabled. First plug in the USB stick, power on your computer, then enter BIOS and check the boot device list.

Comment: @Thomas this might have been lost in the original post: BIOS does not recognize my USB stick, if UEFI is disabled. I.e. I cannot do what you say.

Comment: @Thomas I've got a different USB, which for w/e reason BIOS does recognize. I was able to add it in the bootable devices list by pointing at its bootx64.efi file. I booted with EFI disabled, but anaconda wants me to have EFI partition anyway. Is there anyway to not to use anaconda? Any way to tell it not to try to install with EFI?

Comment: @wxvw: Your answer is self-contradictory. When UEFI is disabled the BIOS boots from the MBR not from any bootx64.efi file. If you want to install in legacy mode then you must boot your computer in legacy mode, from a MBR disk or USB flash drive.

Comment: When you are in non-UEFI mode, you have to put the "USB Stick" into the bootable device list. non-UEFI does not have the capability to boot off a file, just the raw device.

Comment: @AlexP not really. Even when EFI is disabled, I can still go to "Add boot option", which will prompt me for "Name", "Device", "Path" and "Create" dialog, where "Path" expects an *.EFI file. (This is Asus laptop about 6 years old). I don't know why it works this way, but this is the only option I have to add an extra boot device.

Comment: @Thomas what I believe is happening is that despite me disabling EFI in one place, by specifying EFI file in a different place, it chose to use EFI mode. Still, I don't have an option in BIOS to add arbitrary devices as bootable devices. Or, maybe I don't know where to look for it.

Comment: @wxvw: You are doing it all wrong. _In BIOS legacy mode the computer boots from devices not files_. That dialog is useless in legacy mode. You do not _add_ boot devices in BIOS mode. You boot your computer in BIOS mode with the device plugged in, and press the manufacturer-specific key to get a boot menu which lists the bootable devices found, and there you select your device.

Comment: @AlexP well, let me see if there are any other options to add bootable devices, but on the surface of it, this is all I have. Anyways, my question is really different: how can I tell anaconda (and its graphical shell) not to create EFI boot? Why is this garbage not even asking me whether I want this or not?

Comment: @AlexP as I said. If I disable EFI, no USBs are listed as bootable devices. I cannot, obviously, select them, if they aren't listed.

Comment: @AlexP OK. I don't know what do you mean when you say "BIOS mode". Consequently, I don't know what "boot in BIOS mode" is. But, when I access BIOS settings, I can configure it to use legacy USB support (this option is enabled). I can configure it to enable EFI and / or ROM boot. When I enable EFI, I see my USB stick as bootable. When I enable ROM, I see a CD as bootable (but not USB). When both are disabled, none appears in the bootable devices list.

Comment: @wvxvw: You should look for support on how to boot your computer from a USB flash drive in BIOS or MBR mode.

Comment: @AlexP why is this even needed if all I want is that anaconda program doesn't create a boot configuration that I don't want? It is not the problem of how my computer boots now, it's the problem of this crappy installer, that doesn't expose the option that I need.